# How to fetch data from PDO array in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I used mysqli to fetch all data from mysql to array in php, I did as follows:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    $arr = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {     
       $arr[] = $row;
    }
```

Now I've decided to switch to the other way and use:

```
$q3 = $conn3->prepare("select...";
    $q3->bindParam(':ad1', $ad1);
    $q3->bindParam(':ad2', $ad2);
    $q3->execute();

$check = $q3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!empty($check3)){
```

How can I fetch all data to the array, as in example above? Thanks, and sorry for dumb question, I'm just starting my adventure with php..

Comment: try fetchAll instead fetch

Comment: By using [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). In your case: `$q3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`.

Comment: Thanks! after using fetchAll, how can I make direct call similar to ` while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {     
       $arr[] = $row; ` ?

Comment: `while($row = $q3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {`?